# Prevent early validation when using autocomplete and "updateOn: 'blur'"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6, angular-forms

My Angular app uses complex validations executed on the server side. For that reason, I've configured that updates and validations are only triggered on *blur* events:

```
this.form = new FormGroup(
    { ... },
    {
        updateOn: 'blur'
    }
);
```

It works nicely except for fields that use autocompletion. If the autocompletion is open and the user clicks an entry with the mouse, an unfortunate sequence of events occurs:

- A *blur* event is triggered
- Validation runs with the incomplete old value and adds an error
- The selected autocomplete value is put into the field
- The autocompletion popup is closed and field gains the focus again

The result looks as shown below (simplified example). A valid value is in the text field but it's marked as an error because the validation was run on the old value.

[image]

Technically, it's correct that the validation was run because clicking the autocompletion popup causes a *blur* event. However, from a UI perspective it's nonsense. The validation should occur when you're done with the field and move on to the next field.

So how can I prevent the *blur* event and the early validation?

I've created a simple [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jqlldq). It uses a similar setup but runs the validation on the client side (and checks that the text starts with 'ABC'). To reproduce the problem, enter "34" and then select "ABC34" from the autocompletion popup with your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

for triggering on character change we should trigger input event also autocomplete change event, so you can try something like this:

in component:

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild , ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { VERSION } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  @ViewChild('textInput') textInput: ElementRef;  




  version = VERSION;
  form: FormGroup;
  abcText: string = 'ABC1';
  anyText: string = '';
  public readonly abcChanges: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  public abcSuggestions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      abcText: new FormControl(this.abcText),
      anyText: new FormControl(this.anyText)
    }, {
        updateOn: 'blur'
      });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.validateData(val)}

    );

    this.abcSuggestions = this.abcChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.generateSuggestions(val))
    );
  }

  private validateData(val: any) {
    console.log(val)
    // Would be more complex and happen on the server side
    const text: string = val['abcText'];
    const formControl = this.form.get('abcText');
    if (text.startsWith('ABC')) {
      formControl.setErrors(null);
    } else {
      formControl.setErrors({ abc: 'Must start with ABC' });
    }
  }

  private generateSuggestions(val: string) {
    let suggestions = [];
    if (!val.startsWith('ABC')) {
      suggestions.push('ABC' + val);
    }
    suggestions.push('ABC1');
    suggestions.push('ABC2');
    suggestions.push('ABC3');
    return suggestions;
  }

    validateOnCharacterChange(value) {
    console.log(value)
    const formControl = this.form.get('abcText');

    if (value.startsWith('ABC')) {
      formControl.setErrors(null);
    } else {
      formControl.setErrors({ abc: 'Must start with ABC' });
    }
    // this.textInput.nativeElement.blur();
  }
}
```

in html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    Angular Material 2 App
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="basic-container">
    <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="abcText" (input)="abcChanges.next($event.target.value)" placeholder="Text starting with ABC" #textInput required (input)="validateOnCharacterChange($event.target.value)">
                <mat-error>Must start with 'ABC'</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="validateOnCharacterChange($event.option.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let val of abcSuggestions | async" [value]="val">{{ val }}</mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="anyText" placeholder="Any text">
                <mat-error></mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    </form>
    <span class="version-info">Current build: {{version.full}}</span>
</div>
```

check the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zi4ofc).

also by using `this.textInput.nativeElement.blur();` you can blur in every event you want, not just click outside the input.
hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But validation on each character is too expensive. In the real app, the validation occurs on the server side and therefore takes some time. That's why I have switched to `updateOn: 'blur'` in the first place. I'm not looking for validating more often, but less often.

Comment: so i think check it on option selected is enough, remove the input event and will be what you want and i think it's not too expensive?!

Comment: Yes, that could be a workaround. It's a bit unfortunate that it's checked twice within a fraction of a section and that it quickly flashes red; but it seems to be working.

Comment: @Codo or you can blur on option selected and automatically validation will be checked.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the solution. How is this supposed to work and improve the above workaround?

Comment: @Codo the problem is validation is checked when you click out of the input and blur it, so in autocomplete when we select an option if we not click out of the input and not blur it validation will not check and will still have the before state(valid or not valid), by check the validation in onselect method or blur the input in onselect the validation will be checked, without click out of the input.

Comment: Sorry, the explanation is too confusing for me. I don't understand it. I currently have my original implementation plus an extra validation when the autocomplete component's `optionSelected` is triggered (from your answer). It seems to work but is slightly ugly as the validation error quickly appears and disappears. What do you propose I change additionally?